# Communities list horizontal line separators are too short

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app

Look like the horizontal lines are too short in communities list page for the iOS-app in landscape mode:

> [image: communities list]

- App Version: 1.7.0
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Comment: I think you should blame the width of device

Comment: @SagarV and my eyes which brought this information to the brain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.7.0.1.

Because the iPad is so big, and it's easy to loose track of content while reading, Apple has a concept of "readable width" for table content.  Basically, they keep content less than X pixels wide and center it.  You can see this in most system apps.

We don't really do that.  I'm gonna say mostly because we didn't think about it in the initial designs but also because it would be awkward with most of out table views that have grey left margins.  Since I'm not going to adopt them in the near future, I just needed to turn them off, with this handy iOS 9 property:

```
self.tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = NO;
```